# Splunk ODBC Error 60

Tags: odbc, splunk

I have installed Splunk ODBC 32-bit with the following configuration for my 32-bit Excel application to access some saved Splunk queries :

```
Data Source name - Splunk ODBC 32  
login ID - myusername
Password -    ********* 
Server  URL - "http://splunkserver:443" 
Unchecked "Verify Server SSL Certificate"
```

However, every time I try connecting to Splunk using Query Editor in Excel , I get this error : 
  **"[60] Unexpected response from server. Verify the server URL. Ero parsing JSON:Expect either an object or array at root"**

The server URL is working fine when I checked it directly from the browser.

Please let me know how this can be resolved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC driver should be connecting to the Splunk Management port, which by default is 8089.
Try `http://splunkserver:8089`, or https.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It took me days but I found the solution. Version 2.1.0 doesn't work with Splunk 6.4.1 You have to use version 2.0.0 You can download it here : https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1606/release/2.0.0/agree/